# LINQ query add extra value after select

Tags: c#, linq, drop-down-menu

i am populating a "Category" dropdown list with LINQ. (Northwind databse)

```
var Category = (from cat in _db.Categories.ToList()
                         select new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Text = cat.CategoryName,
                             Value = cat.CategoryID.ToString()
                         }).ToList();
```

I wish to add an extra value at the beginning of this list to be the filter reset, something like "All" so i expect the dropdown to be something like :

- **All        //added**
- Beverages  // from query
- Condiments // from query

Comment: Is there a particular reason to why you are doing `_db.Categories.ToList()`. The `ToList()` does not seem necessary.

Comment: you are right indeed,i'll get rid of it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    var Category = new[]{ new SelectListItem(){ Text = "All" } }.Concat(
                   from cat in _db.Categories.ToList()
                   select new SelectListItem
                   {
                         Text = cat.CategoryName,
                         Value = cat.CategoryID.ToString()
                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Concat` with an array constant, like this:

```
var Category = new [] { new SelectListItem {Text="All"}}
    .Concat(from cat in _db.Categories.ToList()
        select new SelectListItem {
            Text = cat.CategoryName
        ,   Value = cat.CategoryID.ToString()
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) a value into a list at the desired position. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` has an Insert method:

```
Category.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text="All" });
```